# How can we adjust the height of a parent element depending on its content?

Tags: html, css

I know there are TONS of similar questions about this BUT I have not found a solution so far. In this case, I have a `form` inside the `main`.

Based on what I've read so far, the parent element (`main`) should be given a height of 100vh. However, if I do that, if I add a lot of content to the element (`form`), **the content will render outside of the `form` element**.

If the `main` element has a height of 100%, it will not stretch to the bottom of the page if the content is short.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Height</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html * {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #555;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        header {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        header span, button {
            margin: 5px;
        }
        main {
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: stretch;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        form {
            padding: 0;
            width: 40%;
            background-color: #ddd;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            const myform = document.querySelector('form');
            let $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
            $('longtext').onclick = () => {
                myform.innerHTML = "<p>A lot of content".repeat(100);
            };
            $('shorttext').onclick = () => {
                myform.innerHTML = '<p>Short text';
            };
            $('notext').onclick = () => {
                myform.innerHTML = '';
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <span>Click a button</span>
        <button id="notext">No Text</button>
        <button id="longtext">Long Text</button>
        <button id="shorttext">Short Text</button>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form></form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you saying that you want the main div's height to fit the form's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your CSS style for . Don't use a fixed height just min-height.
It will fill the entire height and if the content grows it'll grow with it.

```
main {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the min-height solution. I ended up putting the min-height into the form instead.